# When the Moshiach establishes the messianic kingdom of Yisroel, will the halacha binding on every Yehud be Sephardi, Ashkenazi or something else?

Tags: halacha-theory, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, messiah, ashkenazi

When the Moshiach establishes the messianic kingdom of Yisroel, what type of halacha will come into force over the nation? Sephardi, Ashkenazi, Mizrachi, psak Rambam, or something else? Or will multiple shittot apply to different groups (tribes?) of Yehudim, as is the case in today's Medinat Yisroel?

Comment: I assume you created this question to leave here unanswered until moshiach comes.

Comment: @user613 lol!! It may well come to pass! Nevertheless, Rav Ovadia Yosef zal was of the opinion that Moshiach will impose Sephardi halachot and minhagim on klal Yisroel: http://www.ynetnews.com/articles/0,7340,L-3772928,00.html  Perhaps others have a different shittah? :)

Comment: Whatever the Sanhedrin decides. Doesn't matter where your from.

Comment: MeirIllumination and @DoubleAA, it sounds like you have answers. If you can flesh them out, I encourage you to post them.

Comment: @MeirIllumination Well, of course. He was sefardi

Comment: I would assume that the Great Sanhedrin in Jerusalem will rule for all of Israel. Yet it is possible that they will remain undecided on some matters and leave it up to lower courts to rule. It is probable that when it comes to Rabbinic laws, they will poll the people to find out if they can handle old and new potential enactments and decide while considering what the people can handle (as a rabbinic law does not go into effect if a majority of the public can't keep it).

Comment: expect big changes. all festivals annulled except purim for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a very good question. If the Igeret of Sherira Gaon is considered, it states clearly that there was no disagreement in regard to halacha originally. That only happened later and as a consequence of a lack of learning.

Part of the redemption and Moshiach's job is to "repair the breaches" within the Torah. Mishnah Torah, Hilchot Melachim 11:1, 11:4

But that said, each individual is required to follow the teachings of his father and grandfather. This is related to keeping minhagim.
See: http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=7215

The Lubavitcher Rebbe explains that part of what Moshiach will do is to reveal a higher level of Torah, meaning a deeper understanding in which the varying practices will be seen to be one Torah. This is the idea of "Torah me'iti tetzei." (Torah will come forth from me.) Isaiah 51:4.

And this is not really such a surprise. An example of this already exists in regard to the inauguration of the Mikdash by Moshe Rabbeinu. Each of the Princes of the tribes brought the offering for their tribe on their assigned day and brought exactly the same offering. But the intention of each tribe was different. Bamidbar Rabbah 13:14

Comment: "But that said, each individual is required to follow the teachings of his father and grandfather. This is related to keeping minhagim. See: http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=7215". That source isn't speaking about moshiach. I would omit that paragraph. But the rest is good, so +1

Comment: Thanks for your response! So the idea is that Moshiach will set a 'baseline' halakhah (something along the lines of the Yad or dinei Yerushalmi http://machonshilo.org/en/eng/component/content/article/62-misc/202-machon-shilo-about-us perhaps?) that everyone must follow, and then every family will then have its own set of minhagim on top of this? Does this mean that the various families will re-coalesce back into their original tribes, and that tribal minhagim will be restored? I imagine the reorganization of halakhah and medinah is greatly helped by having everyone back in a single territory

Comment: As I view it, it is more complex than you are imagining. Mosiach will reveal the unity of it all. Minhagim happen as an adaptation to the unique environment where a community of Jews happened to be. That's why they vary from region to region. Think of them as a kind of halachic DNA. They trace where a person has come from. This is what is expressed by Rambam in Mishnah Torah, Hilchot Melachim, Chapter 12, 1-3.